# Three.js - How to rotate the Geometry before instancing?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a basic `PlaneGeometry` which I'm trying to rotate before instancing

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1 );
geometry.rotateX = Math.PI/2; // ignored when instancing

var material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( { 
    map: textures.carpet[3].img,
    specular:  0x050505,
    shininess: 100
} );
material.needsUpdate = true;

var Mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
// Mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI/2; // ignored when instancing

var positions; // bunch of coordinate positions
addInstancedMesh( Mesh.geometry, Mesh.material, positions );
```

But the initial rotation of the `Mesh` or `Geometry` are ignored.

Is there a way to pre-rotate the geometry or mesh before instancing?

After instancing I can successfully rotate the `InstancedMesh` as a whole, but I don't want that

Comment: `.rotateX()` is a method, thus it has to be called this way: `geometry.rotateX(Math.PI * 0.5);`

Comment: @prisoner849 *facepalm* that did the trick. Can't thank you enough for your help and contributions